Can more than one client be authenticated with an HttpOnly Token
The httponly token is stored in the browser, so if I have two clients running in the same browser accessing the same API, once one of them is authorized to access API methods that require authentication, does the other one also have access? I tested this in practice and that's what happened. I have an application and an intranet, both accessing the same API. When I authenticated myself in one of the applications, the other one was authenticated as a "bonus."
Another question about this, the httponly token is secure because it cannot be accessed by malicious client-side scripts, right? But I can find it using the browser's "dev tools," so even if I can't access it dynamically through malicious scripts, I can still add it to a script in a "static" way, correct?
I found an answer on Stack Overflow stating that it's fine for the user to see the token in the Dev Tools, but I can't understand what the advantage is of using an HttpOnly token instead of a Header token though

I don't think you can see http-only tokens in DevTools
